# Cannot update macOS with new Apple ID

Tags: apple-id, software-update

I have a MacBook Pro with macOS 10.8.5. I am trying to update to High Sierra with a new Apple ID. After entering my Apple ID it says 'This Apple ID has not been used with the App Store, please review your account information.'

When I click Review, it says 'Software update required, to make changes to you need to upgrade your mac to the latest version macOS.'

I dont have any other apple devices to set up my Apple ID with.

Comment: Can you try to download a free application from the app store first, so it can verify your ID?

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are doing that from one of the System Preferences?

If so, log into https://appleid.apple.com/#!&page=signin with that new account in a web browser.

You may have to feed it a credit card or some other payment option because That Is The Way Apple Works (sigh...). Once you have done that you *should* be able to log in and download the new OS.